# What is the "leak" of object properties in Javascript (chrome dev tool)?

Tags: javascript, properties, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

I'm debugging a memory leak in my javascript code using the chrome developper tool and the [Google's 3 snapshot techniques](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wUVmf78gG-ra5aOxvTfYdiLkdGaR9OhXRnOlIcEmu2s/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.g31ec7af_0_58) which i can't recommand enough.

However, now, by looking at the objects allocated between snapshot 1 and 2 in the snapshot 3's view (thoses are leaked objects, if you read the slides), i'm seeing a big bunch of "object properties".

[image: leak of object properties]

What does it mean ?

Does it means that i added some properties (between snapshot 2 and 3) in thoses objects that weren't existing in snapshot 1 and i didn't delete ?

Comment: The _@number_ is the reference to the object in memory, not how many properties it has or how much memory it is taking up. The main thing that prevents GCing is references being kept alive (e.g. assigned as a property of another thing you haven't finished with) or other weird circular references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code did something that forces V8 to create object properties item for OctreeCell.

It make sense to do a warm-up iteration before taking the first snapshot, or just do next iteration for 4th snapshot and look into the objects between snapshot 2 and 3.

Comment: It seems, indeed, that i have a lot less of thoses when i run a warm-up iteration. But i still don't understand how v8 engine could not have allocated the "property" objects for thoses OctreeCell, since they're were allocated and the constructor was called...

Comment: This https://developers.google.com/v8/design article may give you a clue what is going on. Actually v8 guys use every trick that can improve speed.